# Parse.com delete multiple rows using curl

Tags: php, curl, parse-platform

I need to clear data from the class created in parse.com'm using CURL with PHP.

However, I have to put in a foreach so that data and it makes very heavy processing.

Is there any way to delete all rows automated class?

```
foreach($request->results as $item){
    $params = array(
        'className' => 'UltimaMilha',
        'objectId' => 'QE0oL2R4X6,xc3rzlKF7U'
    );

    $request = $parse->delete($params); 
}
```